# Send file with cURL

Tags: php, curl, upload

After several hours of research, I could not solve a problem with PHP and cURL.

When I try to send a file directly from the form, the curl work normally.

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input name="file" type="file" /> <br />
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>

<?php
$temp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$name = $_FILES['file']['name'];

$post = array (
    'file' => '@'. $temp
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
$exec = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
?>
```

The above code is working properly. When I try to use your form, the file is sent correctly.

My problem is that I need to send files that are already on the server.

I tried with the full path to the file "C:/xampp/htdocs/test/photos.zip" but for some reason, does not work.

```
$post = array (
    'file' => '@C:/xampp/htdocs/test/photos.zip'
);
```

Does anyone know how I do to send files that have already been sent to the server?

Edit:

upload.php ( server )

```
<?php
error_reporting( E_ALL );
$upload = $_FILES['file'];
move_uploaded_file( $upload['tmp_name'], 'photos.zip');
?>
```

myuploadtest.php ( localhost )

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input name="file" type="file" /><br />
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>

<?php
$temp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$name = $_FILES['file']['name'];

$post = array(
    'file' => '@'.$temp
);

$url = "http://www.mysite.com/upload.php";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
$exec = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

uploadcurl.php ( localhost )

```
<?php
$post = array(
    'file' => '@C:/xampp/htdocs/test/photos.zip'
);

$url = "http://www.mysite.com/upload.php";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
$exec = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: PHP shouldn't care at all if the file you're sending already existed or is an upload temp file. Check that PHP actually can read that photos.zip file, and if you've got control over the receiving server, see what the upload status is on that end.

Comment: Ok thats confusing; server to client or client to server?

Comment: Hi Marc. Yes, I can read the file. The server return empty page on both cases, but the temp file are sending properly.

Comment: Hi Craig. The client ( my computer ) to server.

Comment: @MarkNeto What are you trying to do with cUrl then?

Comment: I have several files and I want to send this files to the server. I can use the FTP, for example, but I'm studying about curl, php, etc. I just want send the file in my computer to the server. I try send from form and is ok. But if I try send directly, the file does not send. The file "sendfile.php" is in same directory from photos.zip

Answer (score 1):

Here is something you might like to try :

- Use relative paths, i.e., give the path name relative to the php script that you are running.
- In the code above, I think you are missing the declaration of $url.
- I don't quite understand the question `Does anyone know how I do to send files that have already been sent to the server?`  Which server are you sending the file to? (localhost?)

If the relative path doesn't work, could you share the error messages that you are getting?

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to send the file from my computer to server. The return is empty in both cases, but directly of form, is working. The $url = "http://www.mysite.com/upload.php";

Comment: You are saying `the return is empty` . A couple of questions arise , do you have `error_display= On` on `mysite.com`? It is a goodway to debug (not if you are in production). Can you share the upload.php? Are you echo-ing your success in this script?

Comment: the jsbin link isn't showing anything (the code got html commented out) but anyway, its a 3 line script with no output, it only performs the function. So, I think , it would have moved the file and didn't give you any output. Try `if(empty($_FILE['file'])){echo 'file is empty or no such file';} else{//process}` for your reference. Secondly, I am not really sure if giving a 'file' as the parameter name is the correct way to let curl know if that is a file.There are many questions based on that, will let you know if I find any.

Comment: is the file reaching the server? did you try the if(empty($_FILE['file'])) script?

Answer (score 1):

To send a file that's already on the server, locate it with its full path on the server:

```
$post = array(
    'file' => '@'. $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']
);
```

Which is exactly what you did in the first place.