# sending uploaded file to another server via CURL from a CURLed page

Tags: php, curl

I have seen a lot of examples on how upload files with cURL ([Send file with cURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11072103/send-file-with-curl) being probably the closest to what I need), but for whatever reason my scripts are not working.

**What I am trying to achieve**: curl a file upload form from SERVER2, display it on SERVER1. Select a file to upload via this form, submit the form but have it submit to SERVER1, grab the $_POSTS and the $_FILES and then cURL a submission to the form processing script on SERVER2 and display results in SERVER1.

In other words, I have a working file upload and processing interface on SERVER2, but I need to make it look like everything is happening on SERVER1.

This is what I have as far the relevant code on SERVER1:

```
//loop through submitted files
foreach ($_FILES as $k => $v) {
    $settings[$k] = '@'.$v['tmp_name'];
}

$settings = http_build_query($settings);
$cookie= WP_CONTENT_DIR.'/plugins/myPlugin/cookie.txt';
//SERVER1 is a WORDPRESS site

$ch = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $settings);    

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6"); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);     
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url); 

$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

When I output $response (which includes a print_r($_FILES)), files come up as an empty array and the following error is generated: Warning: file_get_contents(@/tmp/phpFITW6K): failed to open stream: No such file or directory.

What am I missing? I noticed that http_build_query is missing from some cURL examples and an array is passed instead, but I get a "does not allow request data with POST requests, or the amount of data provided in the request exceeds the capacity limit. " if I remove the http_build_query line.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: `Warning: file_get_contents(@/tmp/phpFITW6K):` -- why do you have the `@` sign in the file path ?

Comment: I believe it is because of $settings[$k] = '@'.$v['tmp_name']; . As I understand it, I need the @ to pass on a file? This is something I picked up in the examples I reviewed. If I remove the @ from $settings[$k] = '@'.$v['tmp_name']; then the error message does not have it but still can not open the file.

Comment: Don't do http_build_query(). curl is perfectly willing to accept an array for the form fields, and it'll do its own building. You are also assuming that the uploads worked going to YOUR server. you need to check they were successful before trying to pass them on to the other server.

Comment: @Cpt.Pouches in PHP, the at sign (@) is used as an error control operator. It will supress any errors from an expression. All you are doing by adding the @ is hiding errors. see: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

Comment: Removing http_build_query() and keeping '@' in front of the file name did it. I am not quite sure what fixed the "does not allow request data with POST requests, or the amount of data provided in the request exceeds the capacity limit" error, but the file is received and parsed properly on SERVER2 now. Thank you! I do not think I can accept comments as answers, can I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing http_build_query() and keeping '@' in front of the file name did it. I am not quite sure what fixed the "does not allow request data with POST requests, or the amount of data provided in the request exceeds the capacity limit" error, but the file is received and parsed properly on SERVER2 now.